# jQuery UI Links in accordion header not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have the following structure for an accordion:

```
<div class= "accordion">
             <div class = "h3">
                   <div class = 'id'>
                       <span class ="emp_data"><b> Full Name: </b> {FULL NAME} </span> | 
                       <span class ="emp_data" ><b>Employee ID: </b> {ID} </span> | 
                       <span class ="emp_data" ><a class= "assign" href = "../assign.php?sup=000000 " >Assign </a></span>
                   </div>
             </div>
             <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>ITEM 1</li>
                    <li>ITEM 2</li>
                    <li>ITEM 2</li>
                </ul>

             </div>
        </div >
```

I'm using the following to capture the click on the button but is not working:

```
$(".accordion a").click(function() {
              window.location = $(this).attr('href');
              return false;
           });
```

Can someone please help me figure it out why it doesn't work?

Comment: can u make a fiddle .

Comment: "but is not working" Which means? Is event fired or not?!

Comment: @A.Wolff, sorry for the confusiuon, what I mean is that the link is not clickable. Thanx

Comment: @Mario - Use some different code to identify the event, you are using the same behaviour what the anchor does. How you will know the difference that it is working or not?

Comment: try placing an _alert("hello");_ immediately after _$(".accordion a").click(function() {_

Comment: @Ritesh i suppose jquery Accordion prevent default behaviour on all embeded anchor tags, i'm not in touch with jquery UI so it's just a guess

Comment: @GurminderSingh I tried that and nothing happened. Any other suggestions?

Comment: see my answer with fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For testing event working you can do something like this

```
$(".accordion a").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Then you can see how your code works and solve problems

Comment: Correct, I tried that and the console doesn't log the event. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mario then i'll suggest to use delegation: `$(document.body).on('click',".accordion a",function() {/*...*/});` or to set handler after accordion has been initialized

Comment: @Mario Is there a possibility that you click on span without link?

Comment: @Kison, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I thought that you click on {FULL NAME} or {ID}

Comment: @Kison Ok, if I'm understanding correctly then the answer is everything is clickable and will make the accordion slide down except that the button opens another page and should not open the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is being fired.I simply put an alert. See this
 [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seznb/1/)

```
   $(".accordion a").click(function() {
          alert("11111");
          window.location = $(this).attr('href');
          return false;
       });
```

May be there is some js conflict on your page.

**UPDATE:**

```
   <div class= "accordion">
         <div class = "h3">
               <div class = 'id'>
                   <span class ="emp_data"><b> Full Name: </b> {FULL NAME} </span> | 
                   <span class ="emp_data" ><b>Employee ID: </b> {ID} </span> | 
                   <span class ="emp_data" ><a class= "assign" href = "javascript:;" onclick="goAnyWhere('../assign.php?sup=000000');">Assign </a></span>
               </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <ul>
                <li>ITEM 1</li>
                <li>ITEM 2</li>
                <li>ITEM 2</li>
            </ul>

         </div>
    </div>

    function goAnyWhere(hrefs) {
      alert("11111 "+hrefs);
          window.location = hrefs;
          return false;
    }
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seznb/2/).Try it according to your requirement.

Comment: The funny thing is that this is the only code I have on that page, there is no other functionality besides the accordion.